# Why use a memory-optimized table variable instead of a temp table or normal table variable?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, temporary-tables, memory-optimized-tables, table-variable

Table variables have a bad reputation, mostly due to cardinality estimates. However, this reputation was earned before the introduction of memory-optimized table variables. [Microsoft covers some use-cases here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/faster-temp-table-and-table-variable-by-using-memory-optimization?view=sql-server-ver16), but I'm not sold on the benefits. A normal table variable will go in to RAM very quickly, so I don't see how the general benefits of in-memory OLTP will apply for memory-optimized table variables. [This article](https://web.archive.org/web/20140111080518/http://blogs.technet.com/b/dataplatforminsider/archive/2014/01/07/sql-server-2014-in-memory-oltp-memory-optimized-table-types-and-table-variables.aspx) lists some benefits that apply, but its focus is clearly on listing differences rather than benefits.

In what circumstances would a memory-optimized table variable be preferred over a normal table variable or a temp table? To keep the playing ground even, **assume that we are working in a normal stored procedure that has no reference to any memory-optimized tables.** In other words, assume that my only usage of in-memory OLTP is for table variables. Furthermore, let's assume that we are on SQL Server 2022. Assuming a version like 2014 would make answers needlessly complicated.

Comment: There's a lot more to "in memory OLTP" than just being "in memory" - I suggest you have a look at https://www.red-gate.com/library/sql-server-internals-in-memory-oltp

Comment: @MartinSmith I agree, but I fail to see the benefits for table variables of most of the benefits of in-memory OLTP (e.g. no pages).

Comment: I presume you didn't download that PDF and look at things like natively compiled modules?

Comment: @MartinSmith I must admit that I missed that it was free. I'll read more. Thanks. Anyway, I'm aware of natively compiled stored procedures. That's why I specified that "normal" stored procedure.

Comment: @MartinSmith That has been a tremendously useful resource. I'll eventually make the time to read it in full. I thank you. A shame that my reading list is so long.

Answer (score -2):

[In addition to this resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/estimate-memory-requirements-for-memory-optimized-tables?view=sql-server-ver16), circumstances depend on the situation, company, and project you are involved in since memory-optimized tables are not stored on disk.

The biggest circumstance is when you want to create the table variable. For memory-optimized table variables, [creation happens at deployment time, not at runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/faster-temp-table-and-table-variable-by-using-memory-optimization?view=sql-server-ver16).

If you plan to use memory-optimized tables going forward, other [circumstances and limitations include but are not limited to](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2018/09/01/memory-optimized-tables.aspx#:%7E:text=There%20are%20still%20some%20limitations,are%20not%20supported%3B%20and%20more.):

- Can't use data compression
- Replication between other memory-optimized tables only
- Server-level triggers are not supported
- Database-level triggers are not supported

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Okay. In which circumstances would I prefer the memory-optimized variable?

Comment: @J.Mini i updated my answer for the technical aspect. If you think my answer address your question please upvoted or mark it as the answer

Comment: @Community answer updated

Comment: But what does any of that have to do with table variables?

Comment: @J.Mini all of that goes into your strategy. is your question about when to use memory-optimized tables versus normal or temp tables variable? Please see updated answer